# Getting the text of a selected recyclerview (with FireBase usage)

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, textview

I'm trying to get some text from a recyclerview item I have in my fragment. The recyclerview gets its data from Firebase and stores it in a list, then adds all the items to the recyclerview.

What I want to happen is when I click on a button within the cardview of any of the items in the recyclerview, I get the respective text values within the selected option.

My code:

```
public class Products extends Fragment {

private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter;
public RecyclerView productRecyclerView;
ImageButton btnPopupMenu;
String key, keyholder;
TextView productName, productNameHolder;
int position;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_products, container, false);

    productRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rvProducts);
    productRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    final FloatingActionButton btnAddProd = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnAddProduct);
    final FloatingActionButton btnSearchProd = rootView.findViewById(R.id.fabSearchProduct);
    final FloatingActionButton btnRetract = rootView.findViewById(R.id.fabMainRetract);
    final FloatingActionButton btnMain = rootView.findViewById(R.id.fabMain);

    btnAddProd.hide();
    btnSearchProd.hide();
    btnRetract.hide();

    btnMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            btnAddProd.show();
            btnSearchProd.show();
            btnRetract.show();
            btnMain.hide();
        }
    });

    btnRetract.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            btnAddProd.hide();
            btnSearchProd.hide();
            btnMain.show();
            btnRetract.hide();
        }
    });

    productRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    fetch();

    return rootView;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView productType;
    public TextView productID;
    public TextView productName;
    public LinearLayout rootProduct;
    public ImageButton btnPopupMenu;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        rootProduct = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_rootProducts);
        productName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_productName);
        productType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_productType);
        productID = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_productID);
        btnPopupMenu = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ib_popup_menu);
        productNameHolder = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvHolder);

        position = getAdapterPosition();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Position is: "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void setProductName(String string) {

        productName.setText(string);
    }

    public void setProductType(String string) {

        productType.setText(string);
    }

    public void setProductID(String string) {

        productID.setText(string);
    }

}

public interface RecyclerViewClickListener {
    public void recyclerViewListClicked(View v, int position);
}


private void fetch() {
    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("PRODUCTS");

    final FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ProductDetails> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ProductDetails>()
                    .setQuery(query, new SnapshotParser<ProductDetails>() {
                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public ProductDetails parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            return new ProductDetails
                                    (snapshot.child("Product_Name").getValue().toString(),
                                    snapshot.child("Product_Type").getValue().toString(),
                                    snapshot.child("Product_ID").getValue().toString());
                        }
                    })
                    .build();

    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ProductDetails, ViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_products, parent, false);


            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position, final ProductDetails model) {
            holder.setProductName(model.getProductName());
            holder.setProductType(model.getProductType());
            holder.setProductID(model.getProductID());

            holder.btnPopupMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    PopupMenu pm = new PopupMenu(getContext(), view);


                    pm.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, pm.getMenu());
                    pm.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                            switch (item.getItemId()){
                                case R.id.menu_edit_product:

                                    return true;

                                case R.id.menu_delete_product:
                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                                    builder.setTitle("DELETE Product");
                                    builder.setMessage("You are about to delete the selected product. Continue?");
                                    builder.setCancelable(false);
                                    builder.setNegativeButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        }
                                    });

                                    builder.setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                        }
                                    });
                                    builder.show();

                                    return true;
                            }

                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                    pm.show();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    productRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
    getActivity().setTitle("Products");
}
}
```

My main goal is just to get the text of "Product_Name", and set it in a Test textView to check if I get the correct product name of selected recyclerview item.

I will use the text to reference its key from the firebase database, and allow the edit and delete functions to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass an interface to your ViewHolder and handle all the Dialog UI/logic outside the holder. Just get the click into the holder, and trigger a function in your interface, with the position clicked. Set this clickListener in the `onBind`.
And when you declare the interface implementation (into fragment for example), get all the infos of the product by finding the right product in your fetched list with the position, and show the dialog with infos.
Do you see what I mean ?
You can even create Dialog in another class. Create a dialog inside a VH is not a good practice...
And I don't understand why you do that : `position = getAdapterPosition();` in the VH constructor ? The goal of recyclerView is to reuse VH, so the position at creation of VH is useless...

Answer (score 0):

Create a interface first then implement View.OnClickListener  in ViewHolder class . then override method ..

```
public class PlayerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView name;
    TextView jersy;
    CircleImageView imageView;
    OnPlayerClick playerClick;

    public void setOnPlayerListener ( OnPlayerClick playerClick){
        this.playerClick = playerClick;
    }


    public PlayerViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.playersName);

        jersy = itemView.findViewById(R.id.jersey);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.playerCircleImage);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        playerClick.onPlayerClick(view , getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
```

then just call holder.setOnPlayerListener from onBindViewHolder . like this

```
 holder.setOnPlayerListener(new OnPlayerClick() {
        @Override
        public void onPlayerClick(View view, int position) {
             //here you get the view and position
  }
    });
```